# How to set the first picture of every folder as its folder icon?

Tags: command-line, scripts, icons, directory, thumbnails

If there are pictures in folder A, B, C.....Z, how do I automatically set the first picture in each of these folders as its folder icon? Is there a way like a script or something else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### 1. Automatically change folder icon into the first found image inside

The python script below will change the icon of all folders inside a directory (recursively) into the *first* found valid image file inside the folder.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys

# --- set the list of valid extensions below (lowercase)
# --- use quotes, *don't* include the dot!
ext = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif","icns", "ico"]
# ---

dr = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for directory in dirs:
        folder = os.path.join(root, directory)
        try:
            first = min(p for p in os.listdir(folder) 
                        if p.split(".")[-1].lower() in ext)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
              subprocess.Popen([
                  "gvfs-set-attribute", "-t", "string",
                  os.path.abspath(folder), "metadata::custom-icon",
                  "file://"+os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, first))
                  ])
```

*[Download from Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PJwTbj2v)*

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `change_icon.py`
2. In the head of the script, edit, if you like, the list of extensions to be used as valid icon images.
3. Run it with the targeted directory as an argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/change_icon.py <targeted_directory>
   ```

That's it!

### 2. More advanced

...is to make it a right-click option in nautilus:

[image]

The script is slightly different then:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

# --- set the list of valid extensions below (lowercase)
# --- use quotes, *don't* include the dot!
ext = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "icns", "ico"]
# ---

# retrieve the path of the targeted folder
current = os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI").replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ")
dr = os.path.realpath(current)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for directory in dirs:
        folder = os.path.join(root, directory)
        try:
            first = min(p for p in os.listdir(folder) 
                        if p.split(".")[-1].lower() in ext)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
              subprocess.Popen([
                  "gvfs-set-attribute", "-t", "string",
                  os.path.abspath(folder), "metadata::custom-icon",
                  "file://"+os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, first))
                  ])
```

*[Download from Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/C66d0BeC)*

#### To use

1. Create, if it doesn't exist yet, the directory

   ```
   ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` as `set_foldericons` (no extension!), and **make it executable**.
3. Log out and back in, it works.

#### Notes

- This will change the icon of all folders *inside* the right-clicked folder, not of the folder itself.
- Since `os.path.realpath()` is used, this also works if the targeted folder is a link.

---

### EDIT

#### Undo (reset) the custom icons inside a directory recursively

If, for some reason you'd like to reset the icons inside a folder to their default icon(s), use the script below. Simply:

- copy it into an empty file, save it as `reset_icons.py`
- run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/reset_icons.py <target_directory>
  ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for directory in dirs:
        folder = os.path.join(root, directory)
        subprocess.Popen([
            "gvfs-set-attribute", os.path.abspath(folder),
            "-t", "unset", "metadata::custom-icon"
            ])
```

Comment: I found that I had to input the full path, such as "/home/user/folderName"

Comment: If they add this function to Nautilus, it will be a better file manager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42239/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-julianlai).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42239/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-julianlai).

Comment: @JacobVlijm instead of first image in the folder can I make it to choose a unique file, for example `.folder.png` in every folder. this is really helpful for the directories with more than one  image. I've been using this script  and that's one improvement that I'd love to see in it  https://askubuntu.com/questions/900785/how-to-set-folder-icons-of-multiple-folders-automatically-with-a-unique-file

Comment: First script error message: `/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory` but python3 is installed. Is this supposed to work with all gui file browsers?

Comment: Nope. I use geany. I did invoke it without the initial "python3 ". Guess I assumed it was redundant with the shebang. I just noticed that. But invoking it like in the post, I still get an error, albeit a different one. First error is "set_folder_icon.py", line 25, in <module>
    "file://"+os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, first))"

Comment: @LewRockwellFan See https://askubuntu.com/questions/896860/usr-bin-env-python3-r-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Because of this one [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1090433/344926)

Answer (score 0):

"gvfs-set-attribute" in script 1. will make error in python3 Ubuntu 18.0.4

```
This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio set' instead.
```

I change to

```
"gio", "set"
```

Answer (score 0):

bash version to look for the files named `cover.jpg`/`cover.png` under the current path and set them as a folder icons for the container folder:

```
IFS="\n" find . -iname "cover.jpg" -o -iname "cover.png" | read COVER; do \
  gio set -t string "$(realpath "$(dirname "$COVER")")" metadata::custom-icon "file://$(realpath "$COVER")"; \
done
```