# /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I'm trying to make my `.py` files executable so I can run them using `./filename.py`, but its not working for me.

What I did was adding the shebang `#!/usr/bin python3` and used the command `chmod +x filename.py`. When I run `./filename.py` then as normal user, I get the error message below

```
bash: ./filename.py: /usr/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

As superuser, it tells me this instead:

```
sudo: unable to execute ./filename.py: Permission denied
```

Opening the file the usual method (`python3 filename.py`) it works fine.

When I changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` it tells me this:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please do `which python3` to get the location, then `#!/usr/bin/python3` without spaces in the file in question...

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (or less portable `#!/usr/bin/python3`, but it is recommended to use `env`) is the correct shebang. Either you have a typo in that line, or your installation is a bit messed up if there is no `/usr/bin/env` executable. Can you verify it is there using `which env` and/or `/usr/bin/env --version`?

Comment: @ByteCommander, i literally copied and pasted it from the file. no typos there. the exact message i get is `/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory`. the response for which env is `/usr/bin/env`.  the version is 8.25.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I created the file and edited it both with Pycharm and vim.  the second shebang (the one with env in the path) wasn't wrong as much as i can tell. and it doesn't work any better with the right shebang, i get `bash: ./camel_game.py: /usr/bin/python3^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` when using `#!/usr/bin/python3`. the working directory is `~/PycharmProjects/filename`.

Comment: FYI in `vim`, you can use command `set ff=unix` to change the line endings from DOS style (`\r\n`) to Unix style (`\n`) - no need for an external command such as `dos2unix`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem are your line ending characters. Your file was created or edited on a Windows system and uses Windows/DOS-style line endings (CR+LF), whereas Linux systems like Ubuntu require Unix-style line endings (LF).

There is a simple tool that can convert the two different styles for you called `dos2unix`.

Install it by running

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

After that, you can convert files in either direction using one of the commands

```
dos2unix /PATH/TO/YOUR/WINDOWS_FILE
unix2dos /PATH/TO/YOUR/LINUX_FILE
```

Example:

```
$ cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("ok")

$ ./test.py 
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
$ dos2unix test.py 
dos2unix: converting file test.py to Unix format ...
$ ./test.py 
ok
```

---

To also come back to what you tried first, the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin python3
```

is of course wrong. It tries to execute the file `/usr/bin` with `python3` and the filename of your script as arguments. This must obviously fail because `/usr/bin` is a directory and no executable file.

Comment: I had the same issue, file created in Sublime Text 3 (Windows), then uploaded to my Ubuntu server using Filezilla. These instructions solved the issue gracefully.

Comment: Had the same issue, but needed to run this on all files in an entire directory; a search led me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929461/how-can-i-run-dos2unix-on-an-entire-directory), with this answer: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix`