# Smart Window Tiling for Gnome

Tags: gnome-shell, window, tiling

Over the summer, I had the opportunity to use a Macbook for my internship. Although I really did enjoy it, I missed the customization of Ubuntu. However, there was one app that I really missed, called [Mosaic](https://lightpillar.com/mosaic.html). It was a graphical interface to window tiling, where I can drag a window over an icon and its snaps to a respective position and size. Does anyone know of an alternative for Ubuntu, preferably Gnome?

Answer (score 12):

#### Window Shuffler

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Natively on Ubuntu Budgie, but if you don't mind setting up manually, it should work on all window managers that support the dependencies (not wayland): **WindowShuffler**

[image]

It can be used both via GUI as well as via (basic) keyboard support.

- Download & instructions: https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/window-shuffler.
- Overview of its features: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii4n8H4XEzc

Comment: Looks neat. Will it support Wayland some day?

Comment: This looks fantastic! Thanks for sharing this with us! For me, it isn't exactly what I am looking for. I wanted something that had preset locations, and I can drag a window over an icon and it would automatically snap that window to that location. However, I don't doubt that someone will find this very useful!  Nice tool!

Comment: Drop by in chat and remind me to award it in a couple of days...

Comment: @Fabby awesome!!

Comment: @JacobVlijm [I think you can figure this one out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092774/temporarily-switch-to-a-full-screen-hairline-cursor)

Comment: Congrats!  You continue to amaze me!  **:-)**

Comment: @Fabby you're the best, really :)

Comment: shouldn't it work with [XWayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/ch05.html)?

Comment: I would love to have this on a standard Ubuntu!

Answer (score 4):

I found [Shell Tile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/) to be a pretty good alternative for Gnome. However, it isn't as clean as Mosaic.

Answer (score 4):

What about [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/)? It's quite flexible to configure (supports a variety of customizable grid sizes) and supports multiple monitors. You bring the window you want to to apply tiling to focus and manage it through the dialog pop-up with keyboard shortcuts or with the mouse.

I only use Linux so I never heard of Mosaic, but it looks impressive, Shell Tile on the other hand did not look like what I wanted when I tried it. Should I give it another try?

Comment: A combination of gTile and Shell Tile would be fantastic...Maybe I will write something up!